# Limits of two variable functions

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

For the limit as $x,y$ go to $0$ of $\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, when I change the equation to polar coordinates I recieve $\frac{r\cos(\theta)r\sin(\theta)}{r}$. I then factor out and $r$ from both the top and the bottom and get the answer $\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$. The book states the answer is $r\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$. How is there a leftover $r$ to take a limit of?

Comment: On the bottom you have $\sqrt{r^2}$ and on top you have $r^2$.

Comment: There are two r's in the numerator and one in denominator, after cancellation on one remains in the numerator.

Comment: I don't exactly follow how it ends up being r^2 on top?

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac{(r\cos\theta)(r\sin\theta)}r = \frac{r\Big((\cos\theta)(r\sin\theta)\Big)}r.
$$
Cancel that first $r$ that you see in the numerator with the $r$ in the denominator.  You're left with
$$
(\cos\theta)(r\sin\theta).
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some sort of misunderstanding the limit will be $0$. But the reduced form before taking limit is $r \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$ , then $\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$ is bounded. So $x,y \to 0$ imply $r \to 0$. Hence the limit will be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Another manner to evaluate the limit : $$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right| = \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2}y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right| = \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \left|\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2}}\right| |y|$$

Note that $x^2 \leq x^2 +y^2$ which implies $\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2}} \leq 1$ and $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} |y| = 0$

Then $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right|  =  \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \left|\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2}}\right| |y| =  0$ which implies

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = 0$$